# Is the limit of a sequence of random variables unique?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

If $Y$ and $Z$ are two distinct random variables with the same distribution (for example maybe $Y$ is constant equal to $1$ and $Z$ is equal to $1$ almost everywhere), then surely any sequence $X_n$ which converges in distribution to $Y$ also converges to $Z$. This seems to conflict with the fact that convergence in distribution is metrizable, and therefore limits should be unique.

What about convergence in probability, or almost sure convergence?

Comment: @the_candyman What does "unique with respect to a distribution" mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The limits *are* unique - more precisely, they are unique in distribution, i.e. if $X_n \to Y$ in distribution and $X_n \to Z$ in distribution, then $Y$ and $Z$ have the same distribution. If you define a metric $d$ such that

$$d(X_n,Y) \to 0$$

if and only if $X_n \to Y$ in distribution, then you actually define a metric on the space of distributions. This means in particular that

$$d(X,Y) = d(\tilde{X},\tilde{Y})$$

whenever $X \sim \tilde{X}$ and $Y \sim \tilde{Y}$. From this it follows obviously that $X_n \to Y$ in distribution implies $X_n \to Z$ in distribution for any $Z$ which has the same distribution as $Y$.

In contrast, if $X_n \to Y$ in probability (or almost surely), then $Y$ is unique in the sense that whenever $X_n \to Z$ in probability, then $Y=Z$ almost surely.