# Uniqueness of Limit in Convergence in Distribution

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

If $X_n \rightarrow X$ in distribution and $X_n \rightarrow Y$ in distribution , show that X and Y have the same distribution.

My Approach:
Suppose the distribution of X and Y are not same, i.e., $P(X \leq x) \neq P(Y \leq x)$.
We know that $X_n \rightarrow X$ in distribution if for any bounded continous function $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $E[g(X_n)] \rightarrow E[g(X)]$. Similarly, $X_n \rightarrow Y \ \text{in distribution} \ \Rightarrow E[g(X_n) \rightarrow E[g(Y)]$. By assumption $E[g(X)] \neq E[g(Y)]$, so we can find two subsequences $\{n_k\}$ and $\{n_l\}$ s.t. $E[g(X_{n_k})] \rightarrow   E[g(X)]$ and $E[g(X_{n_l})] \rightarrow   E[g(Y)]$. Since two subsequences converge to two different limits, $E[g(X_n)]$ does not converge to a limit which is a contradiction. Hence  $P(X \leq x) = P(Y \leq x)$.

Is the above proof complete?

Comment: I think if you already have the portmanteau theorem, what you've written is correct, though arguably overkill. Without using the portmanteau theorem, you know that at continuity points of the limit CDFs $F_X$ and $F_Y$, you must have $F_X=F_Y$. (This follows from uniqueness of limits in the reals). But CDFs are monotone, hence continuous except perhaps at countably many points. Use this to argue that the jumps in $F_X$ and $F_Y$ are the same as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the limit of a sequence of random variables unique?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/994884/is-the-limit-of-a-sequence-of-random-variables-unique)